# JasperReports: sub-total in column footer below detail multiples pages

Tags: jasper-reports, overflow, footer, overlapping

I have an invoice report. The everything works like a charm but when the detail is huge more than one page. The *Detail* overflow but the `COLUMN FOOTER` appears in every page of the report.

I would like to display the `SUB-TOTALS AND OTHER COMPUTING` exactly when the *Detail* finish and  printed only once.

What I am doing wrong?  Am I doing it in the wrong band?

here is the `IREPORT IMAGE.`
[image]

running example
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you are placing things in the wrong band it should be in the **Summary Band**. As the Column footer is meant to be footer at all the pages to the column so it will print on every single page.

But as per your requirement you need the totals at the end of the report so you can place  all  these elements which you have placed in the **Column Footer** in the **Summary Band**.

That should work for you.

Thanks.